# Boto: small file download works but large file doesnt

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I have a script that works very well in presenting the user with a list of files stored in an S3 bucket which when they select, the file is downloaded and something is then done with the file.

This method works on files up to 600Mb, but when the user chooses another file which is 2Gb is get a Boto exception error stating the file is being used by another process.

```
listname = self.list_ctrl.GetItemText(i)
conn = boto.connect_s3(access_key, secret_key)
bucket = conn.get_bucket('data')
key = bucket.get_key(listname)
key.get_contents_to_filename(key.name)
```

It is really puzzling as it works great for smaller files

Any ideas what may be causing it to fail?